# Google Custom Search Unintentionally Pre-populated by same webpage parameter 'q'

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-custom-search

I have a webpage where it has its own search form that is using the "q" as the GET parameter, when a user try to use that search if there's no result found on that search, I will display the Google Custom Search and let them Google instead. However, when my URL is mydomain.com/?q=test , the Google Custom Search will autopopulate its search field as "test" and trigger the Google search result as well on the same webpage.

I prefer Google custom search not to be autopopulated because I am afraid if this break the adsense policies. But I can't avoid it, my webpage already been using the "q" as parameter, it's not an option for me to change to another parameter.

So does that break adsense policy, if so, how to avoid autopopulate ?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default query parameter from the control panel at Search features > Advanced > WebSearch Settings > Query Parameter Name.
See https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/3037004